# goto was unexpected at this time in my batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

i am trying to make a batch file, but my goto keeps saying "goto was unexpected at this time" here is my code

```
@echo off
if %firstrun% == 5 goto shut
```

Later on....

```
set firstrun=5
```

And lastly

```
:shut

echo o snap

shutdown -s -f -t 120

goto passk
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the batch file? You need to post more than just what you have in order for someone to be able to help you

Comment: It's private. Is it absolutely necessary to find an answer?

Comment: Then obfuscate the sensitive parts. Batch file code for the most part is not that sensitive. But my best guess is that you do not have a value assigned to the firstrun variable so the IF command becomes an error because you have nothing on the left side of the comparison. Put quotes around each side of your comparison.

Comment: That is true, there is no assigned variable at first, but if i add one, every time i run the batch it will think it is the first time running it

Comment: So did that fix your problem.  It should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining because, if `firstrun` is blank, then the command syntax is wrong and fails. The simple solution is to put quotes around the variable and constant being compared.

```
if "%firstrun%" == "5" goto :shut
```

---

Or by checking if the variable is blank beforehand.

```
if defined firstrun (
    rem Variable had a value.
    if %firstRun% == 5 goto :shut
)
```

This method is useful if you want to compare the values of `%firstrun%` to a number, as the quote method in an if statement can mess with that feature.